# Cassandra package repo is redirecting to jfrog, but jfrog domain is redirecting to a signup page

Tags: cassandra

I tried to download the cassandra debian packages today. The redirect to https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/cassandra-deb takes me to a "14 day trial period is up" page.

I saw this:

https://lists.apache.org/thread/09kj80xld5dkt7cv73m6xs56lqh4jd18

Looks like something has gone wrong since then. Is there a new location, or is this a server configuration issue with the debian package repo?

Answer (score 0):

The jfrog artifactory was indeed down for the past 3-4 days, but this issue is now resolved. Feel free to try again.

You can find a similar discussion in: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/338020/284631