# baseurl for cassandra rpm

Tags: cassandra

trying to install cassandra via rpm package and found problem with baseurl. Does anyone know, problem with redirect?

```
[vic@ol9-135 ~]$ sudo yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="cassandra" list available
Apache Cassandra                                                                                                                7.5 kB/s |  11 kB     00:01
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'cassandra': repomd.xml parser error: Parse error at line: 1 (EntityRef: expecting ';'
)
```

or with jfog (unfortunately I'm not familiar with jfrog).?

```
[vic@ol9-135 ~]$ wget https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/41x/
--2024-03-24 13:36:44--  https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/41x/
Resolving redhat.cassandra.apache.org (redhat.cassandra.apache.org)... 35.172.124.167
Connecting to redhat.cassandra.apache.org (redhat.cassandra.apache.org)|35.172.124.167|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/cassandra-rpm/41x/ [following]
--2024-03-24 13:36:45--  https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/cassandra-rpm/41x/
Resolving apache.jfrog.io (apache.jfrog.io)... 18.232.172.199, 18.214.194.113, 3.95.117.170
Connecting to apache.jfrog.io (apache.jfrog.io)|18.232.172.199|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://landing.jfrog.com/reactivate-server/apache [following]
--2024-03-24 13:36:46--  https://landing.jfrog.com/reactivate-server/apache
Resolving landing.jfrog.com (landing.jfrog.com)... 18.214.194.113, 3.95.117.170, 18.232.172.199
Connecting to landing.jfrog.com (landing.jfrog.com)|18.214.194.113|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

my cassandra.repo

```
[vic@ol9-135 ~]$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra.repo
[cassandra]
name=Apache Cassandra
baseurl=https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/41x/
gpgcheck=0
repo_gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS
[vic@ol9-135 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jfrog artifactory](https://apache.jfrog.io/) expired and was down since last Thursday/Friday.

The issue was tracked by ASF at [INFRA-25649](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/INFRA-25649), and was resolved some minutes ago, looks like.
Please try again, it should work now.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Per this documentation, https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/installing/installing.html#install-as-rpm-package it is `/etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra.repo`.

Make sure you perform `sudo yum update` post adding the cache repo prior to attempting to install. As matter of testing, could you also try with other versions like `40x` or `311x`, etc to see if you're hitting the same problem?

Comment: may be this is my local issue, but looks not
```
[vic@ol9-135 ~]$ sudo yum update
[sudo] password for vic:
Apache Cassandra                                                                                                                210  B/s |  11 kB     00:54
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'cassandra': repomd.xml GPG signature verification error: gpgme_op_verify() error: No data
[vic@ol9-135 ~]$
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently experiencing the exact same error.

I tried a lot but it didn't fix it. We may have to wait for Cassandra to fix the problem.